# Storing a vector of all class instances, and calling their member functions

Tags: c++, iterator, instances, member-functions, entity-component-system

How do I create a vector which stores all the instances of a class? Then how do I iterate over them and call one of their member functions?

Here's a condensed example of what I've been trying to do.

```
#include <vector>

struct Entity{

    Entity::Draw(){
        // do drawing things
    }
};

static std::vector<Entity> entities;

Entity player;
Entity enemy;

void renderEntities() {

    for (std::vector<Entity>::iterator iter = entities.begin();
            iter < entities.end();
            iter++) {

        iter->Draw; // Error in the example. I'm using Draw(); in the actual code.
}
```

But renderEntities() isn't doing anything. The Draw member function works, if I use e.g. player->Draw. I'm either screwing up the vector or the iterator or both and I can't figure out how to fix it. I've tried using references and pointers, which I assume is the thing to do, but whenever I try that I get errors that I haven't been able to fix.

UPDATE:
I appreciate all the help, I'm learning a lot. However my render_entities function still isn't doing anything. Here's all the code.

Any function call that starts with terminal_ is from the BearLibTerminal library.

main.cpp

```
#include <BLT/BearLibTerminal.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

#include "entity.h"

const int WindowSizeX{50};
const int WindowSizeY{20};
const std::string Title{"BLT Test"};
const std::string Font{"../res/SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf"};
const int FontSize{24};

bool quit_game{false};

static Entity player;
static Entity enemy;

void initialize();
void handle_input(int key, Entity &entity);
void draw_player(int x, int y, const char *symbol);
void render_entities();
void clear_entities();

int main() {

    initialize();

    while (!quit_game) {

        terminal_refresh();

        int key{terminal_read()};

        if (key != TK_CLOSE) {

            handle_input(key, player);
        }

        else {

            quit_game = true;
            break;
        }

        clear_entities();
    }

    terminal_close();

    return 0;
}

void initialize() {

    terminal_open();

    std::string size{"size=" + std::to_string(WindowSizeX) + "x" +
                     std::to_string(WindowSizeY)};
    std::string title{"title='" + Title + "'"};
    std::string window{"window: " + size + "," + title};

    std::string fontSize{"size=" + std::to_string(FontSize)};
    std::string font{"font: " + Font + ", " + fontSize};

    std::string concatWndFnt{window + "; " + font};
    const char *setWndFnt{concatWndFnt.c_str()};

    terminal_set(setWndFnt);
    terminal_clear();

    player.x = 0;
    player.y = 0;
    player.layer = 0;
    player.symbol = "P";
    player.color = "green";

    enemy.x = 10;
    enemy.y = 10;
    enemy.layer = 0;
    enemy.symbol = "N";
    enemy.color = "red";
}

void handle_input(int key, Entity &entity) {

    int dx{0};
    int dy{0};

    switch (key) {

        case TK_LEFT:
        case TK_H:
            dx = -1;
            dy = 0;
            break;

        case TK_RIGHT:
        case TK_L:
            dx = 1;
            dy = 0;
            break;

        case TK_UP:
        case TK_K:
            dx = 0;
            dy = -1;
            break;

        case TK_DOWN:
        case TK_J:
            dy = 1;
            dx = 0;
            break;

        case TK_Y:
            dx = -1;
            dy = -1;
            break;

        case TK_U:
            dx = 1;
            dy = -1;
            break;

        case TK_B:
            dx = -1;
            dy = 1;
            break;

        case TK_N:
            dx = 1;
            dy = 1;
            break;

        case TK_ESCAPE:
            quit_game = true;
            break;
    }

    player.Move(dx, dy);

    if (player.x > WindowSizeX - 1) {

        player.x = WindowSizeX - 1;
    }
    else if (player.x < 0) {

        player.x = 0;
    }

    if (player.y > WindowSizeY - 1) {

        player.y = WindowSizeY - 1;
    }
    else if (player.y < 0) {

        player.y = 0;
    }

    player.Draw(); // This works.
    enemy.Draw();  // So do this.
    entity.Draw(); // This draws only player.
    render_entities(); // This doesn't do anything.

    // Player X and Y are printed out correctly, Entities is always 0.
    std::cout << "Player X: " << player.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Player Y: " << player.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Entities: " << entities.size() << std::endl;
}

void render_entities() {

    for (auto entity : entities) {
        entity->Draw();
    }
}

void clear_entities() {

    for (auto entity : entities) {
        entity->Clear();
    }
}
```

entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H_
#define ENTITY_H_

struct Entity {

    int x;
    int y;
    int layer;
    const char *symbol;
    const char *color;

    Entity();
    ~Entity();

    void Move(int dx, int dy);
    void Draw();
    void Clear();
};

static std::vector<Entity *> entities;

#endif /* ENTITY_H_ */
```

entity.cpp

```
#include <BLT/BearLibTerminal.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "entity.h"

Entity::Entity() {

    entities.push_back(this);
}

// Entity(const Entity &) : Entity() {}
// I get an "expected unqualified-id" when I uncomment this. Why?

Entity::~Entity() {

    auto iter = std::find(entities.begin(), entities.end(), this);

    if (iter != entities.end())
        entities.erase(iter);
}

void Entity::Move(int dx, int dy) {

    this->x += dx;
    this->y += dy;
}

void Entity::Draw() {

    terminal_layer(this->layer);
    terminal_color(color_from_name(this->color));
    terminal_print(this->x, this->y, this->symbol);
}

void Entity::Clear() {

    terminal_layer(this->layer);
    terminal_print(this->x, this->y, " ");
}
```

In main.cpp, at the bottom of handle_input() you will see...

```
    player.Draw(); // This works.
    enemy.Draw();  // So do this.
    entity.Draw(); // This draws only player.
    render_entities(); // This doesn't do anything.

    // Player X and Y are printed out correctly, Entities is always 0.
    std::cout << "Player X: " << player.x << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Player Y: " << player.y << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Entities: " << entities.size() << std::endl;
```

Comment: 1. Where do you do entities->push_back or analog? 2. Did you try iter->Draw()?

Comment: `iter < entities.end()` should be `iter != entities.end()`

Comment: `iter->Draw;` should be `iter->Draw();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`renderEntities()` does not do anything because you didn't add any `Entity` objects to the `vector`.  When you declare your `player` and `enemy` objects, they are just hanging around in memory, they are not automatically added to the `vector`.  You need to add them explicitly, such as by calling `entities.push_back()`.

I would suggest using the `Entity` constructor and destructor to update the `vector` automatically, instead of you having to remember to do it manually. That way, every `Entity` object is accounted for by `renderEntities()`, eg:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

struct Entity;
static std::vector<Entity*> entities;

struct Entity
{    
    Entity()
    {
        entities.push_back(this);
    }

    Entity(const Entity &)
        : Entity()
    {
    }

    ~Entity()
    {
        auto iter = std::find(entities.begin(), entities.end(), this);
        if (iter != entities.end())
            entities.erase(iter);
    }

    void Draw()
    {
        // do drawing things
    }
};

Entity player;
Entity enemy;

void renderEntities()
{
    for (auto *entity : entities)
    {
        entity->Draw();
    }
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/L9i02L)

---

**UPDATE**: after seeing your full code, I can see that you are still making some mistakes.

In `main.cpp`, there is no `entity` variable in scope of `handle_input()`, so calling `entity.Draw()` should not compile.

The really big mistake is in `entity.h`, though. DO NOT declare your `entities` variable as `static` in that file!  This causes *every* `.cpp` which `#include`'s your `entity.h` file to get *its own copy* of the variable.  This means that `main.cpp` and `entity.cpp` are operating on **separate `std::vector` objects**!  That is why you see `entities` is always empty in `main.cpp` - the `Entity` objects are never being added to the `std::vector` that exists in `main.cpp`, only to the `std::vector` that exists in `entities.cpp`.

You need to move the actual `std::vector` variable into `entity.cpp` (without `static`), and then declare the variable as `extern` in `entity.h` so that all of your `.cpp` files can access and share that **single variable**.

Try this instead:

entity.h

```
#ifndef ENTITY_H_
#define ENTITY_H_

#include <vector>
#include <string>

struct Entity {
    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int layer = 0;
    std::string symbol;
    std::string color;

    Entity();
    Entity(const Entity&);
    ~Entity();

    Entity& operator=(const Entity&) = default;

    ...
};

extern std::vector<Entity *> entities; // <-- extern, NOT static!

#endif /* ENTITY_H_ */
```

entity.cpp

```
#include <BLT/BearLibTerminal.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include "entity.h"

std::vector<Entity *> entities; // <-- real variable, also NOT static!

Entity::Entity() {
    entities.push_back(this);
}

Entity::Entity(const Entity &src) : Entity() {
    *this = src;
}

Entity::~Entity() {
    auto iter = std::find(entities.begin(), entities.end(), this);
    if (iter != entities.end())
        entities.erase(iter);
}

...

void Entity::Draw() {
    terminal_layer(layer);
    terminal_color(color_from_name(color.c_str()));
    terminal_print(x, y, symbol.c_str());
}

...
```

Comment: The original question contained a vector of values, not pointers. The answer should honor the requested specification.

Comment: I appreciate that he showed it with pointers. I did mention in my original post that I've tried using pointers but, what with me being new at this, was getting a bunch of errors that I couldn't figure out how to fix. I like the idea of using the constructor and destructor to update the vector, however I'm getting an error telling me .find is not a member. I've tried including <algorithm> but no dice.

Comment: Why is `entities` `static` ?  Why are `player` and `enemy` not ?  Also, shouldn't `entities` be a static member of `Entity` ?

Comment: @Tibblediggins my bad, I keep forgetting that `std::vector` doesn't have a `find()` method. I fixed it to use `std::find()` instead.

Comment: @SidS when a global variable is `static` it is not accessible to other translation units via `extern`. Ideally, `Entity` should be declared in a `.h` file. I thought about making `entities` be a static member of `Entity`, but figure it is better to keep it private. It might make sense for `player` and `enemy` to be accessible across units, though

Comment: @VictorHavin I changed the OP's code to store pointers instead, because it really doesn't make sense to store objects, since they would have to be copied when pushed into the vector. Why create an entity only to draw a copy of it instead of the original? Also, storing objects risks slicing issues if `Entity` is ever updated to support polymorphism (so descendants can override `Draw()`, etc)

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I am not here to discuss advantages and disadvantages of vectors of pointers. Depending on implementation, copy constructor can be cheaper than operator new.Especially when you populate vector from a static array. Anyway, the author of this question had his reasons and we are not here to tell him he was wrong without asking first what his reason was. The question was not about using objects in array, after all. It was about populating it and calling methods on elements. So why change the code that was not part of the question?

Comment: @VictorHavin read the last sentence in the OP's question. The OP tried to use pointers, but couldn't get it working correctly. I showed a possible way to make it work.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Sorry, did not notice it when I first read it. Was it edited later? In any case, this was not the central part of this question. I still do not think there is anything wrong with implementing this particular code with objects instead of pointers. Without specific context, it is impossible to decide what is better.

Comment: @RemyLebeau entities.push_back(this) in the constructor doesn't appear to be doing anything. If I manually push_back(player) somewhere else in the code, things are working. Any idea why?

Comment: @Tibblediggins [Works fine for me](https://ideone.com/L9i02L). It is not working for you because you still have a major bug in your code. I updated my answer to explain.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau can we use std::any ?

Comment: @sree Why? For what purpose?

Answer (score 1):

You want `iter != entities.end();` rather than `<`. Also, in this code sample you forgot the parentheses after `Draw`.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way with a for loop since c++ 11:

```
for( auto & entity : entities) {
     entity.Draw();
}
```

Comment: Use `auto &entity` instead, otherwise you make a copy on every iteration

Comment: Or, better `const auto & entity`if `Draw` member function is `const`, which is probable.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of way to do this and I will rank them from worst to best (not saying that your way is bad, just that there are better ways in this case).

The issue with your code is `iter->Draw;` --> This is not actually invoking the function, so it should be:

```
for (std::vector<Entity>::iterator iter = entities.begin();
        iter < entities.end();
        iter++) {
    iter->Draw(); // Notice I added ()
}
```

However, there is a better way to do this same thing:

```
// Entity & is important so that a copy isn't made
for (Entity & entity : entities) {
    entity.Draw();
}
```

Now an equivalent (but slightly nicer) version of the above:

```
// Notice the use of auto!
for (auto & entity : entities) {
    entity.Draw();
}
```

Finally, if you later decide you need it to be a vector of pointers, you can have:

```
static std::vector<Entity *> entities;

static Entity * player = new Entity();
static Entity * enemy = new Entity();

...

for (Entity * entity : entities) { // You could also use (auto entity : entities)
    entity->Draw();
}
```

In this case since it is a vector of `raw pointers` and not `smart pointers`, you will need to make sure to loop through the vector and delete the entities at some point before you call entities.clear() or you will have a memory leak.

The nice thing about the final example is that if you later re-organize your code to have other classes `extend` Entity in order to provide their own Draw behavior, your vector will still be able to store pointers to all these new classes and call their Draw() methods.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I'm still having trouble with render_entities though. I've updated my post with the full source code.

Comment: @Stephano Why would you choose to use a vector of raw pointers instead of a vector of smart pointers?

Comment: @RemyLebeau In real code you wouldn't but I didn't want to explain smart pointers in my post so I just left them out

Comment: @Tibblediggins Glad you got your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Entity {
    Entity(string _name):name(_name){} 
    void Draw(){
        // do drawing things
        cout << name << "::Draw" << endl;
    }
    private:
    string name;
};

static std::vector<Entity *> entities;

static Entity * player = new Entity("Player");
static Entity * enemy = new Entity("Enemy");

void renderEntities() 
{
    for( auto & entity : entities){
       entity->Draw();
    }
}

int main()
{
   entities.push_back(player);
   entities.push_back(enemy);

   renderEntities();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are leaking the `Entity` objects.  Consider using `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Entity>>` instead.